# Modelando Borda de um elemento(DIV)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Quero saber como manipulo a borda de uma div.A ideia é que tenha uma borda bem expeça no canto superior direito desse elemento.Ou seja, se a div tiver um formato quadrado de 4 px de cada lado.Quero que no lado direito superior tenha uma borda de 2px de tamanho e bem expeça.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar:

```
border-width: 2px 10px 4px 20px; 
border-style: solid;
```

legenda:

```
border-width: (top border) (right border) (bottom border)  (left border)
```

Exemplo:

```html
<div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background: red; border-width: 2px 10px 4px 20px; border-style: solid;">
texto

</div>
```

Fonte: 
https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_border-width

**Edit**

Borda apenas na right e top da div com 20px de altura e largura

```css
.div {
position:relative;
width:150px;
height:200px;
background: lightgray;
}

.div:before, 
.div:after, 
.div>:first-child:before, 
.div>:first-child:after {
    position:absolute;
    width:20px; height:20px;
    border-color:blue;
    border-style:solid;
    content: ' ';
}

.div:before {top:0;left:0;border-width: 0px 0 0 0px}
.div:after {top:0;right:0;border-width: 4px 4px 0 0}

.div>:first-child:before {bottom:0;right:0;border-width: 0 4px 4px 0}
.div>:first-child:after {bottom:0;left:0;border-width: 0 0 4px 4px}
```

```html
<div class="div">
</div>
```

Comment: Nao é bem isso que estou em mente.Olha esse link ! tem uma imagem que da pra eu mostrar como exemplo.Quero que apenas tenha borda na area circulada de vermelho.https://www.google.com.br/search?q=borda+superior+direita&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjuzp7I9KjXAhWK5iYKHRBCAtkQ_AUICigB&biw=1366&bih=659#imgrc=KmDVb6CG3FeC3M:

Comment: Só na quina da div?

Comment: sim!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Confere agora..

Comment: isso!!Exatamente obrigado !!!Tinha procurado bastante !!